# Expressjs stream file with fetch to backend service

Tags: javascript, express, fetch-api

I have made an endpoint in my expressJs application, which should be able to proxy a large raw binary to a remote backend rest service, without saving anything to memory.

I can see that this relatively easily can be accomplished with [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), by doing something like this:

```
req.pipe(request({method: "POST"}))
```

However, since the request library is deprecated, I want to use fetch instead. Thus far, I have come up with something as follows:

```
app.post("/my-endpoint", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const url = http://link-to-backend.com/

        const request = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: req.body
        });
        request.body.pipe(res);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send("error");
    }
});
```

Above works as expected. However based on above, I would like to know if my approach actually saves `req.body` into memory before proxying the request to the backend api, and how I effectively can validate if it does/doesn't.

Comment: `req.body` is undefined, unless you use special middleware (which you don't say) that fills it. And filling it means holding the entire binary in memory, at least for the middlewares like [`express.raw`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.raw) that spring to my mind.

Comment: Oh yea, so I'm using body parser i.e. `app.use(bodyParser.raw({ limit: "200mb" }));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following middlewares passes the request and response bodies through chunk by chunk, without storing them entirely in memory:

```js
app.post("/my-endpoint", async (req, res, next) => {
  delete req.headers.host; // you may want to delete certain cookies as well
  req.pipe(http.request(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: req.headers
  }).on("response", function(r) {
    res.writeHead(r.statusCode, r.statusMessage, r.headers);
    r.pipe(res);
  }).on("error", next));
});
```

Comment: After receiving the answer for my question given by Michael I decided to accept his answer but I compensated you with additional +1. Thank you again for your explanations!